# Data which shows up as a date in 'mm/dd/YYYY' format on spreadsheet appears as number in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I've loaded data from a delimited .doc file into an Excel workbook application using a querytable.

Subsequently I'm trying to loop through the data on the worksheet and save the data into particular variable types e.g.:

```
string gender = range.Rows.Cells[index + 7].FormulaLocal;
DateTime birth_date =Convert.ToDateTime(range.Rows.Cells[index + 8].FormulaLocal);
int SSN = Convert.ToInt32(range.Rows.Cells[index + 9].FormulaLocal);
```

I get an exception, however with the above code saying

```
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

Now on screen in the worksheet the data in that field reads "07/09/1972"

However in the debugger I'm instead getting a value of "26489" and this seems to be the source of the exception as c# cannot convert this into a DateTime Object.

Anyone know what's going on here and how best to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When converting from Office, you must use the `DateTime.FromOADate` method. This is because Office uses `OLE Automation date`, which is a format where a floating point value is calculated, counting the days from the last of December 1899. The hours and minutes are represented as fractional days, thus adding a few decimals to the value 26489 would result in a time stamp that also represents hours, minutes and seconds.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.FromOADate(26489);
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

will output

```
1972-07-09 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel stores dates as numbers (representing number of days and fractional days since midnight, 30 December 1899) - use [`FromOADate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert to a CLR `DataTime`

```
double dbl = range.Value;
DAteTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(dbl);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(text)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```